# probably elementary but printing the actual name of the pandas variable, not the dataframe itself

Tags: python, pandas

feel like this is a really easy question but my brain is fried.

if i have a couple variables that contain pandas series, how can i reference the variable names themselves instead of the contents, when i try to print. Here's what's going on.

```
first = pd.Series({1:2, 2:4})
second = pd.Series({1:5, 2:7})
all = [first, second]

for i in all:
    print i, 'has a sum of', i.sum()
```

this currently prints the whole dataframe for each variable. how do i end up with an output like :

"first has a sum of 6

second has a sum of 12"

Comment: Why not just store it in a dict: `d={} d['first'] = first d['second']=second` then you can use the key names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd use a dict:

```
In [15]:
first = pd.Series({1:2, 2:4})
second = pd.Series({1:5, 2:7})
d={}
d['first']=first
d['second']=second
​
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k, 'has a sum of', v.sum())
```

output:

```
first has a sum of 6
second has a sum of 12
```

Also don't use a variable name of `all` this shadows the function `all`

**EDIT**

If the order matters then you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
In [20]:

from collections import OrderedDict
first = pd.Series({1:2, 2:4})
second = pd.Series({1:5, 2:7})
d=OrderedDict()
d['first']=first
d['second']=second
​
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k, 'has a sum of', v.sum())
first has a sum of 6
second has a sum of 12
```

Comment: Yes. I would go with this. Dict can be `d = {'first' : first, 'second': second}`

Comment: good answer! i like zipping together lists of keys and values, so that's what I ended up doing but the overall idea is all yours!

Comment: @EdChum - only issue is that dictionaries have no order so for larger inputs and not this MVCE, there would be some output order inconsistencies. any solution for that?